# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How to fix that issue? Please help.

Admin Controller File:
   This is My controller File.

```
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use App\admins;
     class AdminController extends Controller{
        public function register(Request $request){
             $register  = new admins();
             $register->name = $request->input('name');
             $register->email = $request->input('email');
             $register->password = $request->input('password');
             $register->save();
             return redirect('/admin_register')->with('success', 'Register Sucessully!');
         }

        }
```

Routes File:

```
      Route::post('/admin_register',     'AdminController@register')->name('admin_register');
      Route::get('/admin_register',  'AdminController@register')->name('admin_register');
```

Model File

```
     namespace App;
     use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
       class admins extends Model{
        protected $fillable = [
           'name', 'email', 'password',
        ];
    }
```

admin_register.blade:

```
      <form method="post" action="shareholder" role="form"   id="vehicle_form" name="vehicle_form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>

     <div id="success_msg" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">  </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
         <input type="text" name="name" id="vehicle_no"  value="" placeholder="Enter Your Name" class="form-control">
         <input type="text" name="email" id="vehicle_no" value="" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control">
         <input type="text" name="password" id="vehicle_no" value="" placeholder="Enter your Password" class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" value="REGISTER">
      </form>
```

Comment: Your code seems fine check migrations

Answer (score 0):

If the `name` field is not mandatory, make the field nullable in the migration:

```
$table->string('name', 100)->nullable();
```

Also note that element ids should be unique in the document

Answer (score 0):

Your `GET` is pointing on your `register` method.

1. When you try to access `/admin_register` it will try to create a new user but the `$request` will be empty since you didn't `POST` anything.
2. Assuming the request is not empty and pass the `save()` method, it will redirect you on the same method in a loop because of your redirect

Instead add a new method like :

```
public function redirectForm(){
    return view('admin_register');
}
```

and change your routes to:

```
Route::post('/admin_register', 'AdminController@register')->name('admin_register');
Route::get('/admin_register', 'AdminController@registerForm')->name('admin_register_form');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your view

```
 <form method="post" action="{{route('admin_register')}}" role="form"   id="vehicle_form" name="vehicle_form" data-parsley-validate novalidate>

 <div id="success_msg" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">  </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{csrf_token()}}">
     <input type="text" name="name" id="vehicle_no"  value="" placeholder="Enter Your Name" class="form-control">
     <input type="text" name="email" id="vehicle_no" value="" placeholder="Enter your Email" class="form-control">
     <input type="text" name="password" id="vehicle_no" value="" placeholder="Enter your Password" class="form-control">
    <input type="submit" value="REGISTER">
  </form>
```

In your code `action='shareholder'` which is wrong. set it to `action='{{route('admin_register')}}'`

Hope this helps